# How to convert a `List` to `Set` using literals

Tags: flutter, dart, collections, lint, literals

```dart
final _set = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4].toSet();
```

besides [effective dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) suggesting [prefer_collection_literals](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_collection_literals.html)

it really looks like `java` or `c#` rather than dart (no offense)

does anybody knows

> How to convert a `List` to `Set` ***using literals***

(suggesting to add `// ignore: prefer_collection_literals` isn't an answer)

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Set/Set.from.html

Comment: thanks, `Set.from`  isn't a literal, as a matter of fact my linter gives me the same warning,
but you gave me an idea: `Set.from` is actually a `LinkedHashSet` which is an `exception` mentioned here https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_collection_literals.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
main() {
    final list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    final _set = {...list};
    print('set: $_set'); // set: {1, 2, 3, 4}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the same code as `final _set = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4};`.

When you write `{key: value, key: value}` that is a `Map` literal, but if you just do `{value, value, ...}` that becomes a `Set` literal.

Comment: thanks, but you are creating a set, not converting a list to set

Comment: @FrancescoIapicca It would help if you explained why you need to bother using a `List` literal at all instead of directly using a `Set` literal.  Your question doesn't make much sense; either you're initializing a `Set` from a literal, in which case you should just use a `Set` literal directly, or you're initializing a `Set` from some runtime `List`, in which case `Set.of()` or `List.toSet()` would work just as well.

Comment: in my specific case, in an `Assert(...)` I need to check that a list has no duplicate, I struggle to see how the use case this is relevant to the answer that I already accepted
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66226798/9836706